# rails setting and reading a collection of parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scenario where

- a training Drill applies to a group of people playing sport  at a
- certain Grade (Elite, Adult, Junior),
- and  that Drill will develop them to Perform at a certain level (fundamental, advanced)

I am iterating through a Grades list and putting a dropdown list next to each Grade item so that the person creating the training drill can specify how that apply to developing them to perform at the level, as follows

```
<label>How will this drill improve performance?</label>
<% Grade.all.each do |g| %>
   <% if g.activity_id == @drill.activity_id %>
     <p>It will develop
       <%= select(drill, :grade_ids, @performancelevels.map {|p| [p['development_title'], g.id.to_s + "-" + p.id.to_s] }) %>
       performance for the <%= g.name %> level</p>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller I am permitting

```
params.require(:drill).permit(... {:grade_ids => []} ...)
```

When the form submits I am only getting one value passed when I select several

```
Parameters: {... "grade_ids"=>"1-4"... "commit"=>"Create Drill"}
```

Any suggestions on the best way for me to collect up and send through these parameters?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Got this working. Attached javascript to onchange of the dropdown, added the values to a hidden field, then split the values out of the hidden field in the controller